# SAS TO COBOL conversion variable declaration

Tags: variables, compilation, sas, declaration, cobol

Friends,

I am doing SAS to COBOL conversion.I am stuck with below declaration and conversion.So I am getting SOC7 in COBOL run.Please provide some solution.

```
                     IP in SAS - PD3.5
                      OP in SAS - z6.5
```

My COBOL declaration below.
IP s9.9(5);
OP  .9(5);

Please suggest some solution..

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

Packed Decimal is stored one digit per nibble, which is two digits per byte, with the last nibble storing the sign.  The sign nibbles C, A, F, and E are treated as positive; the sign nibbles B and D are treated as negative.  Sign nibbles C and D are referred to as "preferred sign".  A sign nibble of F is considered "unsigned," meaning it is neither positive nor negative, though pragmatically you can think of it as positive for arithmetic purposes.   +123 is stored in two bytes as x'123C', -456 is stored as x'456D'.

The SAS PD informat specifies PD*w*.*d* where *w* is the width of the field in bytes and *d* is the number of decimal places to the right within the field.  So PD3.5 is a 3 byte field (which would store 5 digits and a sign) with all 5 digits to the right of the decimal point.

To obtain the COBOL declaration for a SAS PD*w*.*d* declaration...

*a* = (*w* * 2) - 1

*b* = *a* - *d*

if *b* = 0
PIC SV*d* Packed-Decimal
else
PIC S9(*b*)V*d* Packed-Decimal

The SAS Z format specifies Z*w*.*d* where *w* is the width of the field in bytes and *d* is the number of decimal places to the right within the field.  The field will be padded with zeroes on the left to make it *w* bytes wide.  So Z6.5 specifies a 6 byte output field with 5 bytes to the right of the decimal point.  One byte is taken by the decimal point itself, and unfortunately there is no room for the sign, which may be a bug or may be intentional (perhaps all the data is known to be positive).

```
IP PIC Sv99999 Packed-Decimal.
OP PIC .99999.
```

When you `MOVE IP TO OP` the conversion from Packed Decimal to Zoned Decimal will be done for you by COBOL.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Will try this and let you know.!!

Comment: Hi.. it's worked now..But right now I am getting soc7 to the next field. It's SAS ip and op is
                             Ip =PD6.2,op=16.2

Comment: So I gave  S9(09)v9(02) comp-3 and 9(13).9(02)...Any wrong with this??

Comment: Hi my ip S9(09)v9(02) comp-3 contains zeroes and  op 9(13).9(02) contains spaces..when I moving ip to op I am getting soc7.pls help...