# SAS to COBOL variable conversion

Tags: variables, sas, runtime-error, declaration, cobol

Hi I am doing SAS to COBOL conversion.

My SAS data's are
Ip = PD6.2,
Op = 16.2

In COBOL I wrote like this
Ip = s9(9)v99 comp-3,
Op = 9(13).99

I am getting Soc7.please help to resolve it

Comment: Show your code, show your data. A declaration by itself does not give a S0C7.

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68701733/624463) to your previous question with a generalized formula to obtain the COBOL declaration for any SAS PD declaration.